# print(".",end="") as a poor progress bar, not working

Tags: python, progress-bar

It is not the first time I try to do a cheap progress bar.
It's only to show there's some activity going on, but not polluting too much the output terminal screen.

I always re-try this simple:

```
print(".",end="")
```

I wonder why it only output at the end ? I mean, it will only output at the end of my script, or when another operation will output to screen, after the long long loop is finished.
Is there a way to make it output to screen any time print is called ?

Comment: Flush the stdout. Or call your script with "python3 -u foo.py"

Comment: `print(".",end="",flush=True)`

Comment: @Bhargav Rao . Good ! too bad pypy3.2 doesn't seem to support it yet. I'll stay on python3 for this script.